# Installing DotNetNuke 7 with MySQL and in .Net 3.0 environment?

Tags: mysql, .net, dotnetnuke

I just registered a hosting service from www.amhosting.com and they said that the Server support MySQL and .Net 3.0 only while the site I am installing is DNN 7 which is running with MSSQL and .Net 4.0.

So what is the solution for this case?
Could I run DNN 7 in .net 3.0 environment?
or should I downgrade the DNN to lower version that is able to run in .net 3.0?
How to configure the DNN site to run with MySQL?

Thanks a lot.
Cheers,
Timmy

Answer (score 3):

I think you should change your hosting solution. 
From what I know DNN7 only works with .NET 4.0 / 4.5

MySql - god forbid, you're in a world of pain. I have heard about attempts to make the DNN Core compatible with MySql... but it's only the Core, and any such projects would be outdated in a matter of months, as DNN does release quite often.

Talking about third party modules, which sooner or later you'll be bound to download from codeplex or buy from Dnn store - forget about. no dnn developer out there provides scripts for mysql.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

As Greg states, you won't have an easy time getting DNN working in 2.0 (there was no 3.0, but 3.5 exists) with MYSQL, and you will be limited based on the "provider" for MYSQL.

Go with another hosting company that does Windows Hosting with MSSQL options, there are plenty of them out there for low cost, you'll save a lot more money changing hosting, than you will trying to get mysql working with DNN, and you won't have any upgrade options available to you.